# Does more toolboxes slow down Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Does installing more and more toolboxes slows down loading of Matlab and make it run slow? I believe if one has many toolboxes in Matlab then it will take more time to load them on RAM and when a script is run then Matlab would take more time to search for the function. Am I correct?

Comment: I have pretty much all available toolboxes installed on my university computer and it isn't slower than on other computers I use. Does anybody have other experiences with this?

Comment: I have 2013a on my 5 year old laptop and 2014a on my lab. desktop which is quite new with high configuration. Matlab on my laptop runs very slow, just wanted to know whether uninstalling a few toolboxs will make Matlab faster?

Answer (score 1):

I have all MathWorks products installed on my machine and there's no significant slowdown.

Comment: @rayrye because probably his Matlab is pirate, toolboxes are very expensive and is very unlikely that you are going to use them all as an engineer for example (there are toolbox for economics, etc). Either way, his answer actually is helpful for the question, so... people have different votings

Comment: @JoãoPedro No, it’s not a pirate license, it’s because I’m an ex-MathWorker and they’ve been generous enough to offer me a free all-product license since I left. And while I don’t quite use all of them, I do use a large proportion as i carry out MATLAB consulting in industries from engineering, to finance, to pharmaceuticals.

Comment: @JoãoPedro You really don't know what you're talking about. Sam Roberts is a former MathWorks employee.

Comment: I just offered the reason why people might be downvoting, I didn't accuse him of pirating, thats why I said the word "probably". Chances a random person here is a mathworks employee are low.